# How to add a project to QTCreator

Tags: qt

I have a project with so many files and all the files are either CPP or Java. I want to add this project to QTCreator for code navigation and code completion while editing. I don't need QTCreator for compilation. Can anyone please help me how to add this code to QTCreator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just start a new project, selecting "Project without Qt".

In the new project right click the project folder and select adding an existing directory to it.